# Dynamically generated double quoted string in lambda expression C#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, elasticsearch, lambda

I've numbers which I Adding in the list with `concatenating double quoted` dynamically and putting into the code as follows

```
ArrayList arrRespId = new ArrayList();
for (int i = 0; i < hitsCountRespId; i++)
{
  arrRespId.Add("\"" + jsonRespId["aggregations"]["my_fields"]["buckets"][i]["key"].ToString() + "\"");
} //Adding all numbers in the list with double quoted 

var strDouble = string.Join(",", arrRespId.ToArray()); //"5","6","7"
```

Hey guys I have a code of `lambda expression` which fetches information from `Elasticsearch`

```
var SearchAggregate = client.Search<string>(sd => sd
                    .Index("Index")
                    .Type("Table")
                    .Size(0)
                    .Query(q => q
                        .Bool(b => b
                            .Must(
                                m => m.Terms("QID", new[] { strDouble.tostring() }),
                                m => m.Terms("ProjectID", new[] { "50" }),
                                m => m.Terms("RespID", new[] { abc.ToString() })
                                //m => m.Terms("RespID", new[] { "1","2" })
                                )))));
```

but the problem is when I putting that double quoted string in lambda expression it taking `"\"5\",\"6\",\"7\",....` and my code not returning anything

[image: See what my lambda expression takes it as a request]

i ll Appreciate your help! Thank you

Comment: It should take `"RespId": { "5","6","7","8",...` see image please

Comment: Why are you turning an array of strings into a string containing a load of escaped quotes? Just pass the array of unescaped strings.

Comment: Above one is lambda expression query used for `ElasticSearch` and `Elasticsearch` throws an exception when we send without double quoted string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I saw your code and image output you are doing mistake in understanding what exactly `term` is expecting in lambda expression, **It doesn't expecting double quoted numbers or characters**
`term` expecting a **string array** containing required numbers, Code should be as follows

```
string[]  arrRespId= new arrRespId[50]; //in your scenario you can put `hitsCountRespId` as array size
for (int i = 0; i < hitsCountRespId; i++)
{
  arrRespId[i]= jsonRespId["aggregations"]["my_fields"]["buckets"][i]["key"].ToString();
}
```

and then just put that `string array` in your lambda expression as follows

```
var SearchAggregate = client.Search<string>(sd => sd
                    .Index("Index")
                    .Type("Table")
                    .Size(0)
                    .Query(q => q
                        .Bool(b => b
                            .Must(
                                m => m.Terms("QID", new[] { strDouble.tostring() }),
                                m => m.Terms("ProjectID", new[] { "50" }),
                                m => m.Terms("RespID", arrRespId)                                    
                                )))));
```

I hope it will work for you.

Comment: Thanx again @maxCoder let me implement it and ll revert you ASAP :)

Comment: Hey It worked thanx a lot for code and brief description :)

Comment: Thanks, I'm glad you figured it out, dont forget to mark it as answer